# Executing puppeteer from cron job

Tags: cron, puppeteer

I need to run a puppeteer script from a cron job.  The problem is that puppeteer is javascript, and the cron job doesn't execute the javascript.  What would be the best way to execute my puppeteer script from my cron job?
Or a workaround?
Here is part of my code in my cron job:

```
<?php
//connect to database and retrieve information

echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
'myPuppeteerFunction();',   //this leads to my puppeteer script, which is saved in javascriptFunctions.js
'</script>'; 

?>
```

Comment: Arey your puppeteer running in Node.js environment? (it's hard to tell based on the given information) Where is your cron job set up (on a server, runs locally, is it in a pipeline etc.)?

Comment: Initially, I had installed node on my home computer, and I had the node_module Folder in my root directory of my website.

Comment: Now I have my website on a hosted website.  I copied all the folders that were in my home pc root directory, to the root directory of the website (including the node_module folder).  To my big surprise everything works.  I was expecting on having to install node (somehow, not sure how) to the root directory on my website, but simply copying the node_module folder seemed to to the job.  
Everything works great when I land on the page, but not not with the cron job. The cron job is set up from my hosted website page.